# Rotate docker swarm configs without restart

Tags: docker-swarm

I'm using docker swarm configs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/). My app supports re-reading configs without restart, but when I rotate in a new config (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/configs/#example-rotate-a-config) docker always restarts the app.

Is there any way to avoid the restart when a config is updated (rotated)?

For now we're just using a bind-mounted NFS drive to hold configs, but I'd really like to use docker swarm configs if we can find a way to avoid the restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. And I don't think this will ever be supported outright. Volumes are the way to go.

Comment: Why do you think it won't ever be supported? Is this just a feeling or are there docs/discussions about it somewhere?

Comment: It goes against the idea of immutable deployment. If something in the configuration changes, a redeployment should occur instead of injecting the updated data somehow and hope/assume that the service is able to detect changes in its configuration. So if someone needs this functionality, he can do it with volumes already

Comment: How would you do this with volumes? Volumes aren't shared accross nodes or do you mean a cifs volume I.e file share?